How to use Rxjs in React and use component variables and state
I have a component (not function) with local variables and states. How do I use rxjs in such situations, is it safe to use? Currently, I think it does not see state or local variables. This code is throwing with null reference for this.signedAPI.
this.validators$ = interval(validatorRefreshMillis)
        .pipe(
            tap(x => console.log('finalSignaturesxxx', x)),
            switchMap(() => {
                return from(this.callApi());
            }),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        );

    this.validators$.
        pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        )
        .subscribe((validators) => {
            const signatures = this.setValidatorMappings(this.state.signatures, validators);
            console.log('finalSignaturesxxx', signatures, this.state.signatures, validators);
            this.setState({ signatures: signatures });
        })


callApi = (): Observable<Validator[]> => {
    return from(this.signedAPI.getData(
    ));
}


As long as the subscription is destroyed and you mark this.destroy$.next(); this.destroy$.complete(); on the destroy hook, it won't be a problem. Also make sure you do not have a short interval, might opt for long polling 5000ms like that

the problem is not being able to use class variables and state variables. At the moment observable only see null.

could you provide a stackblitz highlighting the problem you are facing so that it can be debugged, also please share the steps for replication
